# How to match Python and JavaScript time

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm creating a bot that should pass a data at specific time to a site.
The site uses JavaScript for time but my bot is written in Python.
I have compared them individually and Python is about 1.5 seconds later than JavaScript.
Is there any solution I can bring JavaScript time to my Python bot?

Comment: How do you obtain both times? javascript's `new Date()` and python's `datetime.datetime.now()` both get the local system's clock time. Are you sure you obtained both times at the same instant?

Comment: Do you own the site? Can you make code changes?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi For JavaScript I'm not sure but for Python I use ```datetime.datetime.now().time()```

Comment: @HagaiWild No I don't.

Comment: is "the site" and where the "bot" runs the same server? if not, then the reason the two are different has nothing to do with python vs javascript, but rather computerA and computer B have different time

Comment: @JaromandaX No they don't run on the same server. Is there any way to catch the server time that site runs on it?

Comment: how time critical is this? does this need to be millisecond accurate?

Comment: so, you're able to get the time from the site somehow - simply get the time and adjust the timing of the data you pass